# Is there are any framework for ballerina

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I read the documents of Ballerina https://ballerina.io/. I am interesting about Ballerina. Is there are any framework to build the web app using Ballerina?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment there is no Web frameworks similar to ASP.NET MVC or Spring for Ballerina. However you can easily create single page web applications using Ballerina RESTful services. This is similar to ASP.net WebAPI or python with flask.

There you separate the Web pages which are written in HTML/JS.. from the backend APIs which you can write in Ballerina.

Please take a look at this https://ballerina.io/learn/by-guide/restful-service/